# Transparent background in jquery dialog box during an ajax asynchronous call to server

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a jquery dialog box which contain many input fields and a submit button. While submitting the form , an ajax call will fire to server and during this time I need to make dialog box's background as transparent also at this this time submit button should change to ajax loading image.

Please note the commented part inside the ajax function.

My code is here : http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/9396Z/

## Important piece of code.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'some url path',
    type:'GET',
    data:{isPDF:0},                                         
    success:function(data,textStatus,xhr)
    {
        setTimeout(function (){
        // I need some logic to implement here to make a transparent background
        // (so that user cant do any thing on background). Also I need to change
        // the submit button to an ajax loading image.                      
        },2000);

        (event.preventDefault) ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;                                
        $("#prnt_info_sbmt").click();                   
    },              
    error:function(xhr,textStatus,errorThrown)
    {
        alert(errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

Can any one guide me to make this possible. 
Your timely help is well appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you thought about setting `modal:true` on the dialog settings?

Comment: If you go through the fiddle that I provided you can see that. But what is the relevent of this "model:true" in this question. My question is how to set an background image and change the submit button to ajax loading image in this JQuery dialog box once an ajax call got fired.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple approach: [my fiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/Ttp5j/1/)

The main idea is to replace the html inside the button with an image and overlay an empty div over the form at the same time.

#### Relevant JS:

```
setTimeout(function (){
    $(".ui-dialog-buttonset .ui-button").html("<img src='http://placekitten.com/g/65/38'/>")
        .attr("disable", "disabled");
    $("#popup").append("<div class='sheen'/>");
},2000);
```

#### CSS:

```
.sheen {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: but here the cross mark (x) in the close button is also getting removed.

Comment: I added the `.ui-dialog-buttonset` class to the selector so that only buttons in the lower area will be turned into kittens.

Comment: The opacity feature is not working in IE8. I want this to be worked in IE8 too. So I made some changes 1]removed "background : rgba" to "background : rgb" and added opacity separately. but it is not working. Any idea. My code is here http://jsfiddle.net/inDiscover/6AKSn/